# Does reselect memoize in case we return empty array or object as fallback

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, reselect

Assume we have a selector written with createSelector

```
const getSmth = createSelector(
  getState,
  state => state.items || {}
)
```

Does memoization still works or it will recalculate each time cause we return a new reference? As far as I know, reselect does equality check by reference `===`? Or reselect store this to a variable and the reference will be the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getSmth` is a generated selector. `getState` is the input selector, `state => state.items || {}` is the output selector

If the generated selector is called multiple times, **the "output" selector will only be recalculated when the extracted values have changed.**

The calculated result(derived data) has nothing to do with the recalculation. This means the output selector returns the same reference or a new reference does not matter.

> `createSelector` determines if the value returned by an input-selector has changed between calls using reference equality (`===`).

E.g.

```js
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const state = { items: undefined };
const getState = (state) => state;

const getSmth = createSelector(getState, (state) => {
  console.log('[getSmth] resultFunc');
  return state.items || {};
});

getSmth(state);
getSmth(state);
console.assert(
  getSmth.recomputations() === 1,
  'should calculate once if the reference passed into the selector is the same',
);

const getSmth1 = createSelector(getState, (state) => {
  console.log('[getSmth1] resultFunc');
  return state.items || {};
});

const shallowCopy = (state) => ({ ...state });

getSmth1(shallowCopy(state));  // memorize input for first call
getSmth1(shallowCopy(state));  // compare input of second call with the input of first call using `defaultEqualityCheck`(`===`)
console.assert(getSmth1.recomputations() === 2, 'should caculate twice if a new reference passed into the selector');
```

Output:

```bash
[getSmth] resultFunc
[getSmth1] resultFunc
[getSmth1] resultFunc
```